# How to POST Chunked Encoding in R

Tags: r, http

I have a large oracle query result and want to upload it using http POST.

But with memory constrain, I cannot read all rows at once into memory.
So I read a few rows at a time, but can't find a way to start chunked uploading in R.

If it were in C# it would go something like this

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://myserver/upload");
req.SendChunked=true;
req.method = "POST"
using(var s = req.GetRequestStream()){
    while(queryResult.hasRow()){
        byte[] buffer = queryResult.readRow();
        s.write(buffer,0,buffer.Length);
    }
}
resonse = req.getResponse();
```

Is there anything equivalent in R?